# Can gas line installed perpendicular to floor joists be tight to the joists?

Tags: gas, remodeling

When the previous owner added an island with a cook top, the gas line they installed was hung about 2" below the floor joists. It runs perpendicular to the joists just below the island. They had to remove ceiling tiles to run the line (and drainage pipes for the dishwasher) and now the ceiling looks like a demo project that never got refinished.

Can the gas line be tight to the joists, so a new ceiling can be put in and not lose so much ceiling height? Or could it possibly go inside the joists so no ceiling height is lost?

Comment: Please post a photo if you can

Comment: If you can drill in from the rim joist you *can* run iron pipes through joists (and patch the hole in the rim joist after you get the pipe in place.) But CSST probably makes more sense these days.

Comment: Are you sure it's not suspended below to clear other objects, say near the ends? Otherwise it was probably done because the vertical pipe lengths used were at hand.

Comment: Rigid gas pipes can be strapped directly to the bottom of the joist.  If you have access, you might consider rerouting the pipes *through* the joists.

Answer (score 2):

There are no restrictions on location of gas lines in relation to building structure. Piping in concealed spaces has restrictions on types of fittings that can be used, and required protection measures for less robust types such as CSST.

Answer (score 1):

Under UK regulations, gas pipework is allowed within the fabric of the building, to answer your question, yes it can go against or inside the  joists, after moving the pipe it would require a tightness test as it’s the only way of knowing there is no leaks.

[https://www.hse.gov.uk/pubns/priced/l56.pdf][1], (Page 17)